# NSMutableDictionary key values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

is it true that the key values for NSMutableDictionary can only be strings?

I was trying to use objects, but I am getting a warning.

Comment: when using Key-Value Coding, the keys have to be strings; but otherwise, they can be anything that implements NSCopying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> In general, a key can be any object
>   (provided that it conforms to the
>   NSCopying protocol—see below), but
>   note that when using key-value coding
>   the key must be a string (see
>   Key-Value Coding Fundamentals).

What warning are you getting?

Comment: as it turned out my class did not implement the protocal

Comment: yeah - definitely make sure you implement the "hash" method in your object. Otherwise, you can get two different objects appearing identical in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use any object, but the object must implement `-[NSObject hash]`, `-[NSObject isEqual:]`, and the `NSCopying` protocol.

Comment: well all objects that inherit from NSObject implement `-hash`. it is only if you override `-isEqual:` that you have to make sure the `-hash` is compatible with `-isEqual:`

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at header file of NSMutableDictionary, the add function can take id as the key:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey;
- (void)removeObjectForKey:(id)aKey;
```

So you can use virtually anything as the key and value.